# How to get path of installation of target game/application from registry when installing mod/plugin using Inno Setup?

Tags: registry, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to create installer for mod of the game. And I need to detect where is installed the game. I know where is path of the game in registry. But the game can be in another launchers - Steam, GOG. How to detect in order?

For example:

- If I have steam version need to detect path of installation from registry for steam
- If I have GOG version need to detect path of installation from registry for GOG
- If I have both versions (Steam and GOG) then default path of installation will be for steam version
- If I don't have any versions then user own choose destination

Registry keys:

- Steam:

  ```
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 475150] 
  "InstallLocation"="E:\\Games\\Software\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Titan Quest Anniversary Edition"
  ```
- GOG:

  ```
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\GOG.com\Games\1196955511] 
  "path"="D:\\Titan Quest GOG"
  ```

I know how detect one path

```
DefaultDirName={reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 475150, InstallLocation}
```

But I don't know how detect many paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) and [`RegQueryStringValue` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regquerystringvalue):

```pascal
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={code:GetInstallationPath}

[Code]
var
  InstallationPath: string;

function GetInstallationPath(Param: string): string;
begin
  // Detected path is cached, as this gets called multiple times
  if InstallationPath = '' then
  begin
    if RegQueryStringValue(
         HKLM64,
         'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 475150',
         'InstallLocation', InstallationPath) then
    begin
      Log('Detected Steam installation: ' + InstallationPath);
    end
      else
    if RegQueryStringValue(
         HKLM32, 'SOFTWARE\GOG.com\Games\1196955511',
         'path', InstallationPath) then
    begin
      Log('Detected GOG installation: ' + InstallationPath);
    end
      else
    begin
      InstallationPath := 'C:\your\default\path';
      Log('No installation detected, using the default path: ' +
            InstallationPath);
    end;
  end;
  Result := InstallationPath;
end;
```