# Is it possible to get the app directory path inside the InitializeSetup?

Tags: inno-setup

If I make an update, I need the path to destination directory, where previous version was installed. I need it inside the `InitializeSetup` function.

`UsePreviousAppDir` is enabled, but neither `{app}` variable is initialized nor `WizardDirValue` is created.

Comment: Why do you need it in `InitializeSetup`? Give us details about what you are trying to implement.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, our company have some clients, who are working together on the single terminal server, and they have to have the separate installations of software.
To make an update, I try to use the MD5-hash of installation location (as mutex), to be sure, that the instances only from selected client will be closed.
I could make it with an AppId as a Mutex, but it's not so easy, to get AppId from my C# application.

Comment: You do not have to use mutex. Inno Setup will detect that the application in the destination directory is running (as the exe file is locked) and will close it. See `CloseApplications` directive.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, this way suits me very well, thanks for saving my time!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I found out that it doesn't work in multiuser mode. So if the app is running by another windows user, inno doesn't see it. 
And it also looks like a bug, because if I start app by another user and by current user at the same time - inno also does not suggest to close an app running by current user.

Comment: So, I think I would still use mutex, but I found out, that I could check it inside PrepareToInstall method. So, the {app} will be already available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read `InstallLocation` value in the installer's registry keys.

For an example, see [How to get path of installation of target game/application from registry when installing mod/plugin using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56576172/850848)

---

*Though there may be a better solution to what you are trying to implement. If you tell us what that is.*

Comment: I would not rely on the internal Inno Setup implementation registry key. I'd prefer writing my own registry key and read its value with every update setup.