# How to find installed directory in inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I have created an installer using innosetup. Where User can choose the directory where he wants to install by setting up DisableDirPage=No but when it comes to patch installers it is failed to update as user has been installed the app to his preferred directory. How to make installer to identify in which directory the app has been installed and make the patch installer to work.

installer code:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir = c:\test
OutputBaseFilename=update
DisableDirPage=No

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
```

Comment: Well, that obviously depends on the application you are patching (and its installer), which you told us nothing about.

Comment: Though, see [How to get path of installation of target game/application from registry when installing mod/plugin using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56576172/850848)

Answer (score 0):

If I unterstand you correctly you are talking about the setuo for your own application. You can put the `UsePreviousAppDir` directive in your `[Setup]` section. It's not necessary because its default value is 'yes' anyway. The documentation (http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) says that the Setup is looking for the same application, which is defined by the `AppId` or the `AppName`.

As long as you use `AppName=My Program` like in your example code, Inno Setup should find the install path of the old version itself. But if the `AppName` or `AppId` changes in your new version, there is no way to find it in the registry. A changing `AppId` is likely if you use a new guid for every setup.