# How to access the path of Inno Setup installed program from OUTSIDE of Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

According to the docs, Inno Setup uses `AppName` or `AppId` to allow you to create an update program that will automatically put its files in the same path which the user installed the initial application to.

I need to be able to determine where Inno Setup installed files to based on `AppId`, but NOT from within Inno Setup. For example, I need to be able to determine this from a Python script.

One use case: patching a file in the installed program location. It would be overkill to package an entire installer just to, say, conditionally add or edit a line in a text file. A simple Python script could accomplish this, plus the user could review the script if they desired. I cannot and should not assume the user just installed to the default location, hence why I need to be able to see where the user installed the program.

Inno Setup obviously stores this somewhere since it is able to make its own patches, but I can't seem to find it in the registry. I've searched the Registry for my app ID but I only see it in the `Uninstall` section. I can probably pull it from there, but I think you can also create installers without uninstallers – where would this end up in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is stored to registry to `HKLM` (administrative install mode) or `HKCU` (non administrative install mode) to a subkey named after the `AppId` with `_is1` suffix, stored under a key `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` (as you alraedy know). The value name is `Inno Setup: App Path`. The path is also stored to `InstallLocation` with additional trailing slash, as that's where Windows reads it from. But Inno Setup reads the first value.

An example for `HKLM`:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\appid_is1]
"Inno Setup: App Path"="C:\\Program Files\\My Program"
"InstallLocation"="C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\"
```

You can see this in dozens questions, that show how to read the value in Inno Setup code. For example:
[How to get path of installation of target game/application from registry when installing mod/plugin using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56576172/850848)

---

If you create an installer what cannot be uninstalled (`CreateUninstallRegKey=no` or `CreateUninstallRegKey=no`), then the path is not store anywhere. In such case you would have to explicitly code your installer to store the path for you *somewhere*.