# Find Steam installation directory in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, steam, pascalscript

I want my installer to find the user's Steam folder and install the game there

The Steam folder is like `F:Steam/steamapps/sourcemods`

Because everyone has Steam downloaded to different drives and folders, the installer needs to find the `sourcemods` folder in the Steam root folder.

I do the installer in Inno Setup.

Please help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to get path of installation of target game/application from registry when installing mod/plugin using Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56576172/850848)

You just need to modify the code to look into appropriate registry key, as shown in the answer by @IneedHelp.

```pascal
RegQueryStringValue(
  HKCU, 'SOFTWARE\Software\Valve\Steam', 'SourceModInstallPath',
  InstallationPath)
```

Answer (score -1):

The path you're looking for is stored in the registry under `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam` in the `SourceModInstallPath`. You could grab it as such:

```
string keyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam";
string valueName = "SourceModInstallPath";
string sourceModInstallPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, null);
```

Comment: and where to insert it? It's just that I use the template from the inno setup itself, you chose the custom installation location setting, I pasted this instead of the usual folder installation folder. For some reason it didn’t work, to be honest I don’t know the hell about C #